# Invalid hook call. ReacJs

Tags: reactjs

I have been troubleshooting this error for hours now.
I'm using the hooks on top of a function (getItems). i don't know what mistake i have done.
How should i clear this?

ERROR:
`

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function
> component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
> and fix this problem.

`

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";

const data = {
list: [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "A1",
    list: [
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "A2",
      },
    ]
  },
]
 };
  function getItems() {
    const [menuStack, setStack] = React.useState([data.list]);

    const pushState = (list) => {
        list && setStack((stack) => [...stack, list]);
    };
    const popState = () => {
        menuStack.length > 1 && setStack((stack) => stack.slice(0, -1));
    };

    const top = menuStack[menuStack.length - 1];
    return (
        <button onClick={popState}>BACK</button>
    );

}
export default class PopUp extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {getItems()}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from "react";
export default class Home extends React.Component {
render(){
 return (
 <App />
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: I think `getItems` is being interpreted as a function that may or may not be called? I'd try making it a component: `function GetItems() {...}` and then calling it as one `<GetItems />`

Comment: When I changed it to component, it's working. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with class getItems, You can use that as a Component. `<GetItems />`

```
import React from "react";

const data = {
  list: [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: "A1",
      list: [
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "A2",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
function GetItems() {
  const [menuStack, setStack] = React.useState([data.list]);

  const pushState = (list) => {
    list && setStack((stack) => [...stack, list]);
  };
  const popState = () => {
    menuStack.length > 1 && setStack((stack) => stack.slice(0, -1));
  };

  const top = menuStack[menuStack.length - 1];
  return <button onClick={popState}>BACK</button>;
}

export default class PopUp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GetItems />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling function getItems inside your PopUp component and expecting to print the output. React treat that function as a normal function and hence throws that error.

You need to tell react that this is a component function by doing

```
<div>
<getItems />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In react, hooks can be written in functional components. But you called `getItems` function as a general function, not a functional component.

You should let react treat as a component like following:

```
<getItems />
```